# How to prevent an element to be assigned in the same index?

Tags: python

I'm trying to set out five "B"s in a grid like format randomly, but sometimes the code sets a "B" when there is already one.

I expect the outcome to look like this:

```py
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', '0', '0']
['B', '0', 'B', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

but sometimes I get outcomes like this:

```py
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', '0', '0']
['B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Here is my code -

```py
def board():
    grid0 = []
    grid1 = []
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0

    while a < 8:
        grid0.append("0")
        a += 1

    while b < 8:
        grid1.append(grid0.copy())
        b += 1

    while c < 5:
        grid1[random.randint(0,7)][random.randint(0,7)] = "B"
        c += 1

    for row in grid1:
        print(row)
```

Comment: If the current cell already contains a `B`, keep re-generating the coordinates

Comment: Make a list of all the coordinates, using something from `itertools`. Shuffle the list, take the first 5 elements, then use those coordinates as the places to put B.

Comment: create 8 lists with various B positions, shuffle the list.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the element already has `B` in it before adding it and incrementing the counter.

```
    while c < 5:
        x = random.randint(0,7)
        y = random.randint(0,7)
        if grid1[x][y] != "B":
            grid1[x][y] = "B"
            c += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if it already contains a 'B', and if it does, try again!

```py
while c < 5:
    r,c = (random.randint(0,7), random.randint(0,7))
    if not grid1[r][c] == "B":
        grid1[r][c] = "B"
        c += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pprint import pprint
import random

# using a list comprehension to create the grid
grid = [
    ['0'] * 8  # -> append ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'] to `grid`
    for i in range(8)  # -> 8 times
]
print('GRID:')
pprint(grid)

# generate an index 5 times
for _ in range(5):
    while 1:
        # keep generating an index until an index without 'B' is found
        x, y = random.randint(0, 7), random.randint(0, 7)

        # if an `empty` index is found, assign 'B' to it and move on to the next index
        if grid[x][y] != 'B':
            grid[x][y] = 'B'
            break

print('\nGRID:')
pprint(grid)
```

Output:

```
GRID:
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]


GRID:
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', '0'],
 ['0', 'B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', 'B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', 'B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Barmar's approach, but here's a different way to think about it:
only add +1 to c if the total amount of "B"s has changed.

```
while c < 5:
    start_count_b = sum([row.count("B") for row in grid1])
    grid1[random.randint(0,7)][random.randint(0,7)] = "B"
    end_count_b = sum([row.count("B") for row in grid1])
    if end_count_b > start_count_b:
        c += 1
```

the list comprehensions take each list (row) in your grid1, count the amount of "B"s in it, and appends that number it to a list. The sum of this resulting list is the amount of Bs in your entire grid.

Comment: This would unnecessarily increase time complexity.